# Ruby: Why freeze mutable objects assigned to constants?

Tags: ruby, string, rubocop

Consider this offense reported by rubocop

```
lib/awesomelib/aws.rb:6:10: C: Style/MutableConstant: Freeze mutable objects assigned to constants.
    IP = '34.111.241.111'
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why should I freeze this IP address?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should freeze the value assigned to `IP` because you've declared `IP` to be a constant. This indicates that you don't want the value assigned to `IP` to be mutated.

The problem is that in ruby, assigning a value to a constant does not make the value immutable. You just get a warning if you mutate the value assigned to the constant. To make the value actually immutable, you need to `.freeze` the value assigned to the constant. After you've frozen a value assigned to a constant, if you try to change the value, you will hit a runtime error.

Comment: You are confusing variables and objects.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I agree that my original phrasing was sloppy, so I've revised it. Thanks.

Comment: @jk_ : Aside from the increased safety, is there also a performance advantage in freezing a constant?

Comment: @jk_ maybe you know how to `freeze` multiline literals?

Comment: "You just get a warning if you mutate the value assigned to the constant." - nope, not even a warning. You're thinking of constant redefinition warning, perhaps?

Answer (score 20):

Freezing an object means you are no longer allowed to mutate it. A constant means you are no longer allowed to mutate the binding. (Well, okay, you get a warning if you mutate the binding.) The two just go together well.

In particular, the fact that a mutable object assigned to an immutable binding can still be mutated, might be confusing to some. Just witness the various questions on Stack Overflow about it:

```
IP = '34.111.241.111'
# Dis is a constant, I can never change it, amirite?

IP << '.255'

IP
#=> '34.111.241.111.255'
# Ooops!

IP.freeze

IP << '.255'
# RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
```

Comment: Note: `IP = '192.168.1.1'` is still possible and will still result in a warning, not a error.